# How to know whether an update was successful while updating using azure offline sync?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-data-sync

In the android client app if we update a row in local DB by using azure mobile sync services as follows, then how can we know whether the update was successful ?

```
mToDoTable.update(workflows).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`mTodoTable.update(workflows)` returns a ListenableFuture where E is the type of your record.  You can do anything normal, including adding onSuccess/onFailure callbacks to the async call. More information on the ListenableFuture here: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained

Also, check out the Azure Mobile Apps SDK Docs: http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/